# Simplify this expression as much as possible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

I am working on a proof and I am stuck on this problem. I have this expression that I want to simplify this as much as possible but I don't get how. I want to try removing the "$...$" using possibly the geometric series formulas.

Given some $x$ such that $x ≠ 2^k$ for some k, the following formula can be satisfied by picking some $m,φ ∈ ℕ^+$ and $β,...,δ,α ∈ ℕ$.

$\frac{3^m}{2^{α+δ+⋯+β+φ}}x+\frac{3^{m-1}}{2^{δ+⋯+β+φ}}+...+\frac{3^{1}}{2^{β+φ}}+\frac{3^0}{2^φ}=1$

These properties of the expression must also be satisfied:

- There are $m+1$ terms on the left side.
- The numerator decreases its exponent by $1$ from $m$ to $0$.
- On the denominator, from the right side to the left side, the
  exponent is $φ$, then the next term is $φ + β$, and it keeps getting
  non-smaller as you go left. There is no relationships between these
  exponent values.
- Also for all terms on the left side, the denominator is always
  strictly bigger than the numerator.

Does anyone know any math trick that can make this look prettier?

Thanks

---

**Here is some sample data I have collected:**

$\frac{3^{2}}{2^{5}}3 + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{5}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{1}}{2^{4}}5 + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{2}}{2^{6}}6 + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{5}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{5}}{2^{11}}7 + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{6}}{2^{13}}9 + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{13}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{1}}{2^{5}}10 + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{4}}{2^{10}}11 + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{2}}{2^{7}}12 + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{5}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{2}}{2^{7}}13 + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{5}}{2^{12}}14 + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{5}}{2^{12}}15 + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{12}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{3}}{2^{9}}17 + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{6}}{2^{14}}18 + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{13}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{6}}{2^{14}}19 + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{14}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{13}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{1}}{2^{6}}20 + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{1}}{2^{6}}21 + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{6}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}}22 + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}}23 + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{2}}{2^{8}}24 + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{5}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{7}}{2^{16}}25 + \frac{3^{6}}{2^{16}} + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{14}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{13}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{2}}{2^{8}}26 + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{41}}{2^{70}}27 + \frac{3^{40}}{2^{70}} + \frac{3^{39}}{2^{69}} + \frac{3^{38}}{2^{67}} + \frac{3^{37}}{2^{66}} + \frac{3^{36}}{2^{65}} + \frac{3^{35}}{2^{64}} + \frac{3^{34}}{2^{63}} + \frac{3^{33}}{2^{61}} + \frac{3^{32}}{2^{59}} + \frac{3^{31}}{2^{58}} + \frac{3^{30}}{2^{56}} + \frac{3^{29}}{2^{55}} + \frac{3^{28}}{2^{54}} + \frac{3^{27}}{2^{52}} + \frac{3^{26}}{2^{51}} + \frac{3^{25}}{2^{50}} + \frac{3^{24}}{2^{49}} + \frac{3^{23}}{2^{47}} + \frac{3^{22}}{2^{44}} + \frac{3^{21}}{2^{43}} + \frac{3^{20}}{2^{42}} + \frac{3^{19}}{2^{40}} + \frac{3^{18}}{2^{39}} + \frac{3^{17}}{2^{37}} + \frac{3^{16}}{2^{36}} + \frac{3^{15}}{2^{35}} + \frac{3^{14}}{2^{34}} + \frac{3^{13}}{2^{33}} + \frac{3^{12}}{2^{32}} + \frac{3^{11}}{2^{29}} + \frac{3^{10}}{2^{28}} + \frac{3^{9}}{2^{27}} + \frac{3^{8}}{2^{26}} + \frac{3^{7}}{2^{22}} + \frac{3^{6}}{2^{20}} + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{18}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{14}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{5}}{2^{13}}28 + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{5}}{2^{13}}29 + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{13}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{5}}{2^{13}}30 + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{12}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{39}}{2^{67}}31 + \frac{3^{38}}{2^{67}} + \frac{3^{37}}{2^{66}} + \frac{3^{36}}{2^{65}} + \frac{3^{35}}{2^{64}} + \frac{3^{34}}{2^{63}} + \frac{3^{33}}{2^{61}} + \frac{3^{32}}{2^{59}} + \frac{3^{31}}{2^{58}} + \frac{3^{30}}{2^{56}} + \frac{3^{29}}{2^{55}} + \frac{3^{28}}{2^{54}} + \frac{3^{27}}{2^{52}} + \frac{3^{26}}{2^{51}} + \frac{3^{25}}{2^{50}} + \frac{3^{24}}{2^{49}} + \frac{3^{23}}{2^{47}} + \frac{3^{22}}{2^{44}} + \frac{3^{21}}{2^{43}} + \frac{3^{20}}{2^{42}} + \frac{3^{19}}{2^{40}} + \frac{3^{18}}{2^{39}} + \frac{3^{17}}{2^{37}} + \frac{3^{16}}{2^{36}} + \frac{3^{15}}{2^{35}} + \frac{3^{14}}{2^{34}} + \frac{3^{13}}{2^{33}} + \frac{3^{12}}{2^{32}} + \frac{3^{11}}{2^{29}} + \frac{3^{10}}{2^{28}} + \frac{3^{9}}{2^{27}} + \frac{3^{8}}{2^{26}} + \frac{3^{7}}{2^{22}} + \frac{3^{6}}{2^{20}} + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{18}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{14}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{8}}{2^{18}}33 + \frac{3^{7}}{2^{18}} + \frac{3^{6}}{2^{16}} + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{14}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{13}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}}34 + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}}35 + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{6}}{2^{15}}36 + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{13}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{6}}{2^{15}}37 + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{15}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{6}}{2^{15}}38 + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{14}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{13}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{11}}{2^{23}}39 + \frac{3^{10}}{2^{23}} + \frac{3^{9}}{2^{22}} + \frac{3^{8}}{2^{21}} + \frac{3^{7}}{2^{19}} + \frac{3^{6}}{2^{18}} + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{14}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{13}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}}40 + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{40}}{2^{69}}41 + \frac{3^{39}}{2^{69}} + \frac{3^{38}}{2^{67}} + \frac{3^{37}}{2^{66}} + \frac{3^{36}}{2^{65}} + \frac{3^{35}}{2^{64}} + \frac{3^{34}}{2^{63}} + \frac{3^{33}}{2^{61}} + \frac{3^{32}}{2^{59}} + \frac{3^{31}}{2^{58}} + \frac{3^{30}}{2^{56}} + \frac{3^{29}}{2^{55}} + \frac{3^{28}}{2^{54}} + \frac{3^{27}}{2^{52}} + \frac{3^{26}}{2^{51}} + \frac{3^{25}}{2^{50}} + \frac{3^{24}}{2^{49}} + \frac{3^{23}}{2^{47}} + \frac{3^{22}}{2^{44}} + \frac{3^{21}}{2^{43}} + \frac{3^{20}}{2^{42}} + \frac{3^{19}}{2^{40}} + \frac{3^{18}}{2^{39}} + \frac{3^{17}}{2^{37}} + \frac{3^{16}}{2^{36}} + \frac{3^{15}}{2^{35}} + \frac{3^{14}}{2^{34}} + \frac{3^{13}}{2^{33}} + \frac{3^{12}}{2^{32}} + \frac{3^{11}}{2^{29}} + \frac{3^{10}}{2^{28}} + \frac{3^{9}}{2^{27}} + \frac{3^{8}}{2^{26}} + \frac{3^{7}}{2^{22}} + \frac{3^{6}}{2^{20}} + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{18}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{14}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}}42 + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{6}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{9}}{2^{20}}43 + \frac{3^{8}}{2^{20}} + \frac{3^{7}}{2^{19}} + \frac{3^{6}}{2^{17}} + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{15}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{4}}{2^{12}}44 + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{4}}{2^{12}}45 + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{12}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{4}}{2^{12}}46 + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{38}}{2^{66}}47 + \frac{3^{37}}{2^{66}} + \frac{3^{36}}{2^{65}} + \frac{3^{35}}{2^{64}} + \frac{3^{34}}{2^{63}} + \frac{3^{33}}{2^{61}} + \frac{3^{32}}{2^{59}} + \frac{3^{31}}{2^{58}} + \frac{3^{30}}{2^{56}} + \frac{3^{29}}{2^{55}} + \frac{3^{28}}{2^{54}} + \frac{3^{27}}{2^{52}} + \frac{3^{26}}{2^{51}} + \frac{3^{25}}{2^{50}} + \frac{3^{24}}{2^{49}} + \frac{3^{23}}{2^{47}} + \frac{3^{22}}{2^{44}} + \frac{3^{21}}{2^{43}} + \frac{3^{20}}{2^{42}} + \frac{3^{19}}{2^{40}} + \frac{3^{18}}{2^{39}} + \frac{3^{17}}{2^{37}} + \frac{3^{16}}{2^{36}} + \frac{3^{15}}{2^{35}} + \frac{3^{14}}{2^{34}} + \frac{3^{13}}{2^{33}} + \frac{3^{12}}{2^{32}} + \frac{3^{11}}{2^{29}} + \frac{3^{10}}{2^{28}} + \frac{3^{9}}{2^{27}} + \frac{3^{8}}{2^{26}} + \frac{3^{7}}{2^{22}} + \frac{3^{6}}{2^{20}} + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{18}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{14}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}}48 + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{5}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{7}}{2^{17}}49 + \frac{3^{6}}{2^{17}} + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{15}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{11}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$
$\frac{3^{7}}{2^{17}}50 + \frac{3^{6}}{2^{16}} + \frac{3^{5}}{2^{14}} + \frac{3^{4}}{2^{13}} + \frac{3^{3}}{2^{10}} + \frac{3^{2}}{2^{9}} + \frac{3^{1}}{2^{7}} + \frac{3^{0}}{2^{4}} = 1$

Comment: The $\frac 1 {2^x}$ are really "arbitrary"(we just know that they are decreasing) coefficients. So you are basically asking to simplify $a3^n+b3^{n-1}+c3^{n-2}+\cdots $. I don't think that is possible. But you can arrange them in a number of ways, searching for the most numerically stable expression or whatsoever.

Comment: tip: rename the exponents using subscript notations. It easens up finding a compact form. As for simplifying the sum it is difficult as we don't know any relationship between the exponents of the 2's.

Comment: I've added some sample data incase you want to see.

Comment: Besides from factoring the last coefficient ($2^w$) I don't think there is something to do(in general). Why do you want to simplify this? How could this possibly be important in a proof? What are you trying to prove? Maybe that gives some clues about what to do, or just leaving the approach you are trying to use. P.S.: This took a ton of time to render in my poor phone.

Comment: I was thinking if the exponents in the denominator isnt increment by 1, maybe I could just add those terms like (+1-1), and then rearrange them so they all do increment.

Comment: Please, answer my questions(or justify why you can't/shouldn't). Now, what do you mean by *I could just add those terms like (+1-1) and then rearrange them so they all do increment*?

Comment: If there is no regularity in the exponents which appear in both numerator and denominator, I do not think that any significant simplication of the formula could be achieved (except at the price of a massive usage of Kronecker symbol).